# How can I groupby the datetime hour to have a calculation in dataframe and output as time interval result?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, pandas-groupby

The information on `df` is below:

```
df:
datetime               value_1   value_2
2019-01-01 00:00:00       1         2
2019-01-01 00:15:00       2         2
2019-01-01 00:30:00       0         2
2019-01-01 00:45:00       4         3
2019-01-01 01:00:00      10        10
2019-01-01 01:15:00       1         2
2019-01-01 01:23:00       1         2
2019-01-01 01:45:00       1         2
2019-01-01 01:55:00       1         2
2019-01-01 02:00:00      99        99
...
```

And I want to sum up the value by the group and it can output the hour interval result like below:

```
datetime_1             datetime_2          sum_value_1       sum_value_2
2019-01-01 00:00       2019-01-01 01:00          7                9
2019-01-01 01:00       2019-01-01 02:00         14               18
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
new_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='1h')).sum()
print(new_df)
```

Output

```
                     value_1  value_2
datetime                             
2019-01-01 00:00:00        7        9
2019-01-01 01:00:00       14       18
2019-01-01 02:00:00       99       99
```